# Google Maps API v3 navigation (like Google maps for android)

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In our app we do use the Google Maps API a lot. The app (web) is build in Jquery, CSS, HTML.
The app runs in the browser.

But we like to add the navigation functions like the Android Google Maps native in our webapp.

Is that possible with the Google Maps API or do we need to convert to native to realise 
something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a long winded answer introducing the [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), luckily I re-read the question before answering...

No there is no Javascript equivalent of the android navigation services unless I'm very much mistaken. I imagine it would be possible to create a custom solution (I presume you want the route to update as you travel based on your gps coords etc) leveraging the route-parts returned from a [directions request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Routes) but this would be none trivial.

I would have thought the simplest solution would be to pass the start and end points of your route to the native maps app, however I am no expert at Android development (or interaction between a web app and a phone).

Comment: But other apps eg UberPartner has turn by turn navigation in there app right ? Any idea how they must've done it ? Got permission from Google and used custom code?

Comment: I would imagine a massive multi-million $/£ company like uber would have no issues writing it from scratch.